# Swift: Copy ALAsset into app's documents directory

Tags: swift

I'm trying to copy the content of an ALAsset into my app's documents directory like so:

```
let assetRep: ALAssetRepresentation! = alAsset.defaultRepresentation()
let sizeOfRawDataInBytes: Int = Int(assetRep.size())
var rawData: NSMutableData = NSMutableData(capacity: sizeOfRawDataInBytes)
var bufferPtr: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void> = rawData.mutableBytes
var bufferPtr8: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8> = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>(bufferPtr)

var error: NSError? = nil
assetRep.getBytes(bufferPtr8, fromOffset: 0, length: sizeOfRawDataInBytes, error: &error)

if error != nil {
    NSLog("%@ %@", error!.userInfo!, error!)

    if completion != nil {
        NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock { () -> Void in
            completion!(error: error)
        }
    }
} else {
    NSFileManager.defaultManager().createFileAtPath(path!, contents: nil, attributes: nil)
    rawData.writeToFile(path, atomically: true)

    if completion != nil {
        NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock { () -> Void in
            completion!(error: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Some values when trying to writeToFile:

```
alAsset    = (ALAsset!) 0x17d6f770
completion = (((error: NSError!) -> ())?)
path       = (String!) "/var/mobile/Applications/3C2E3C85-8F24-4CF1-958D-5D79A3200BE0/Documents/BEC3072C-45E9-4BC9-85C9-54FB6D9A1562.JPG"
rawData    = (NSConcreteMutableData *) 0 bytes
bufferPtr  = (UnsafeMutablePointer<()>) 0x03b9f000
bufferPtr8 = (UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>) 0x03b9f000
error      = (NSError?) nil
assetRep   = (ALAssetRepresentation!) 0x1468e6b0
sizeOfRawDataInBytes = (Int) 1118987
```

My NSData is empty after trying to getBytes from assetRep. Is there another way to convert `UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>` to `UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>`? I would like to have the bytes from the asset in my NSData so that I can easily writeToFile.

**[EDIT]**

Instead of:

```
rawData.writeToFile(path, atomically: true)
```

I've just tried this and it worked:

```
let newData: NSData = NSData(bytesNoCopy: bufferPtr8, length: sizeOfRawDataInBytes, freeWhenDone: false)
newData.writeToFile(path, atomically: true)
```

It seems that bufferPtr and bufferPtr8 are not the same after all, but their values are the same at run time.

Is it possible to convert and pass the NSData's mutableBytes directly to getBytes?

Comment: your tip about pointers help me. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @AndreiMarincas, did you ever figure this out? I'll use your newData workaround for now, but would also like to know if there's a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, you need to use:

```
var rawData: NSMutableData = NSMutableData(length: sizeOfRawDataInBytes)
```

instead of `NSMutableData(capacity: sizeOfRawDataInBytes)`.

`rawData.length` was still set to `0`, because `assetRep.getBytes` only sets the data at a given pointer, it doesn't tell `rawData` that the data is actually present.

I think you were actually running the risk of memory corruption here, because if you init with `capacity`, it doesn't always allocate the memory straight away. [Check out the NSMutableData docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableData_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableData/initWithCapacity:).

Comment: Thanks, I will try it soon but this is indeed the correct usage. Haven't used this exact code in a while because it doesn't work for large files like videos, they need to be copied in chunks of bytes.

Comment: I actually just used this code to test out a video file (22MB), and it seemed to work fine for me. Although now, I'm thinking about using AVAssetWriter to encode the video on the device to make it a bit smaller before uploading.

Comment: Mine was a much larger video (~500MB), and I was copying multiple files at the same time in a bg thread, leading to memory alloc problems sooner or later. So it depends how it is used.